# Cities Near By a City Webservice or PHP code

Tags: web-services, geolocation, distance, city

I am building an application which takes 'City','State' ( For USA Only)  and  distance ( radius ) as user inputs and the output will be all the cities in that radius . Is there any free or paid web service available for this ?

Thanks for your help
Regards
Kaveri

Comment: I havent used one in a while and even then only for geocoding complete addresses, but i think nearly any maps api (google, yahoo, etc..) is going to allow you to do this. Its probably not a single call to the api but the functionality should be there to implement it on your end once you have the geodata for the initial point.

Comment: Thanks for your comment .I checked google API but confused a bit . I downloaded geodata from http://ipinfodb.com/ for my work . It has all the needed information . I found API to get the distance between two cities (ZIP codes) but unfortunately I have to check against all the Cities to get the required result.I am sure there should be some way to get it in easy way.If you look at http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm on right hand side box they are providing all the cities nearer to your IP . I am some what looking for the same , But in my case user enters City info and the distance .
-Kaveri

Answer (score 1):

I personally use lat and lng to define such a radius. Take a look at my code if you need help coverting an city to coordinates Google Geocode can be really helpfull. or just reply and we'll take a look.

```
/**
 * @author Stefano Groenland
 * @return string
 *
 * Uses the geobyte API for nearby cities in a radius arround the lat & long coords of a given location.
 */
public function getLocationsInRadius(){
    $radius = Input::get('radius');
    $lat = Input::get('lat');
    $lng = Input::get('lng');

    $radius = $radius * 0.62137; //km to miles
    $url = 'http://gd.geobytes.com/GetNearbyCities?radius='.$radius.'&Latitude='.$lat.'&Longitude='.$lng.'&limit=999';

    $response_json = file_get_contents($url);

    $response = json_decode($response_json, true);

    return $response;
}
```